# java.net.SocketException:connectionreset with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, socketexception, connection-reset

everytime it is getting the same error like 
    java.net.SocketException

```
in java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at Server.TcpServer.main(TcpServer.java:37)
my code at the following line....

phonenumber = Long.parseLong(query, inFromTcpClient.read());
thanks in advance...
```

Comment: connection has been closed by the server end of the connection. This could be an issue with the request you are sending or an issue at their end.

Comment: can you show the server and client program

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have **not** put your `.accept` in to a loop, which means the connection between the client and server is being as eclipse says `reset` as all it does is connect, then disconnect.

Generally its like

```
try {
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        // do something with socket (and close it afterwards!)
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    // we're outta here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, the client needs to run their Command Prompt in Administrator mode, and type the command:

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
```

This should prevent the instance of java.net.Socket from prematurely closing its connection.

[check this link also](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-networking/17319-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset.html)